# understanding "undefined is not an object('this.props.navigation.navigate)"

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I am getting the error "undefined is not an object('this.props.navigation.navigate)" when I click the button titled with "Chat with Lucy" which is supposed to take me to the ChatScreen screen.

All of this code is within the App.js file i'm using that is being exported into the android and ios files.

Any reason why i'm getting this error? thanks!

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View, 
  Image,
  TextInput,
  Button
} from 'react-native';


export default class firstapp extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Welcome',
  };
  render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Image source={require('./Packit_title.png')} />
        <TextInput
          style={styles.account}
          />       
        <TextInput
          style={styles.account}
        />

        <View style={styles.button}>
          <Button
            title="Login" 
            color="#c47735"

          /> 
          <Button 
            title="Sign Up" 
            color="#c47735"
          /> 
        </View>

        <Button
          onPress={() => navigate('Chat')}
          title="Chat with Lucy"
        />

      </View>
    );
  }
}


class ChatScreen extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Chat with Lucy',
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Chat with Lucy</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const firstappNav = StackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: firstapp },
  Chat: { screen: ChatScreen },
});

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#f49542',
  },
  account: {
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
    height: 40, 
    borderColor: 'gray', 
    borderWidth: 1,
    marginBottom: 10,
    width: 200
  },
  button: {
  flexDirection: 'row',
  }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('firstapp', () => firstapp);
```

Comment: this is because props is undefined in firstapp Component. You will have to override its constructor to access props. Read this: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#constructor

Answer (score 0):

You are exporting your `firstapp` component which has no access to the `navigation` prop since nothing is being passed to it. You need to export your navigator component `firstappNav` instead.

```
AppRegistry.registerComponent('firstapp', () => firstappNav);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because props object is undefined in firstapp Component. You will have to override its constructor to access props. [Read this](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#constructor)